# How to make an Android Web Server?

Tags: android, c++, http, web, simplehttpserver

How do i make an application like kws which allows our handheld device to act as a server. It should be able to handle post request and host a web site. Any idea where I should start?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you are developing in C++.

You can start with [HappyHTTP](http://scumways.com/happyhttp/happyhttp.html) library from Ben Campbell and [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to create your small web server on an Android. Both can be quite easily compiled for Android and work well. If you need to handle only get/post requests it is more than enough.

Here's an example how to do it in C++: https://github.com/corporateshark/Android-NDK-Game-Development-Cookbook/tree/master/Chapter3/8_MakingWebServer

Comment: HappyHTTP and libcurl are both client http library, not server.

Comment: @AIMINPAN libcurl can be used as a generic sockets library. HappyHTTP can we used as a building block for an HTTP server. Here's how to do it: https://github.com/corporateshark/Android-NDK-Game-Development-Cookbook/tree/master/Chapter3/8_MakingWebServer

Comment: Why isn't this mentioned in any other place than some book's repo? I think this should be Android standard stuff.